# Drag and Drop Items in Grid View WP8/8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to implement Drag and Drop arrangement of individual items in Grid in WP8/8.1, just like the Live tiles(assuming i can resize items also)
It should also be scrollable.

The UI should be like the one like this : http://gridster.net/

I've tried WrapPanel, WrapGrid but Dragging using Gesture Listener is very difficult as a ScrollViewer also scrolls and the drag isnt smooth as expected.

Is there any control or library i can try ??? or any other ways to implement the tile like interface in an WP8 app ?